# Weird RegEx behavior in C#: seemingly incorrect results for Regex.Ismatch class

Tags: c#, regex

```
        string entryStr = "3";
        Console.WriteLine(entryStr);
        Regex regex = new Regex("[abcdef]");
        Regex numRegex = new Regex("[0123456789]");

        Console.WriteLine("entryStr: " + entryStr);
        Console.WriteLine("[a-f]: " + regex.IsMatch("entryStr"));
        Console.WriteLine("[0-9]: " + numRegex.IsMatch("entryStr"));
        /* result: 
        entryStr: 3
        [a-f]: True
        [0-9]: False
        */
```

I'm trying to work with Regex, and it gives me seemingly wrong results.
I need to check if a certain string fits one Regex pattern or another.
I wrote this code, and the code seems correct to me, but it seems to give a wrong result and seems to consider the string "3" as fitting the "[a-f]" pattern and not the "[0-9]".

What did I misunderstand?

Thanks for the replies and sorry for the fundamental question.

Comment: This is basically a typo

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the string literal `"entryStr"` to `isMatch()`, when you really want to pass the variable itself by the same name.  That is, use this version to get your expected results:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("entryStr: " + entryStr);
Console.WriteLine("[a-f]: " + regex.IsMatch(entryStr));
Console.WriteLine("[0-9]: " + numRegex.IsMatch(entryStr));
```

This prints:

```
entryStr: 3
[a-f]: False
[0-9]: True
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake! Thanks for the answer!